# Node.js Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node and running into this error on a simple tutorial.

I am on the OS X 10.8.2 trying this from CodeRunner and the Terminal.
I have also tried putting my module in the `node_modules` folder.

I can tell this is some kind of connection problem but I have no idea why?

```
events.js:71
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:761:19)
```

app.js:

```
var makeRequest = require('./make_request');

makeRequest("Here's looking at you, kid");
makeRequest("Hello, this is dog");
```

make_request.js:

```
var http = require('http');

var makeRequest = function(message) {

    //var message = "Here's looking at you, kid.";
    var options = {
        host: 'localhost', port: 8080, path:'/', method: 'POST'
    }

    var request = http.request(options, function(response) {
        response.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
    request.write(message);
    request.end();
};

module.exports = makeRequest;
```

Comment: I also put this code up on `https://c9.io/` and get the same error.

Comment: Open for incoming our out coming or what? Same issue on a node server using the service defined ports and host. If you actually know what is going on here post a real solution not vague comments as stated in the question I am new to node.

Comment: @ian, Nowhere in your cod are you creating a server.  So, what do you have running on port 8080 that you are trying to connect to?

Comment: For any future readers I was trying to make an API request to a PHP server and my request port was not set to 80.  Once changed my http requests worked fine.

Comment: I was running node 17 (on a M1 Mac) and I removed it via `brew uninstall node` and then install node 16 with `brew install node@16`. Worked a treat. I _may_ have had to `brew link --force node@16` but I can't remember right now.

Answer (score 71):

Chances are you are struggling with the node.js dying whenever the server you are calling refuses to connect.  Try this:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This keeps your server running and also give you a place to attach the debugger and look for a deeper problem.

Comment: Keeping your server running after an uncaught exception is a dangerous thing to do. You do not know if the exception left your server in an expected state. It's much safer to kill the server and have another process restart it (and log the exception, obviously).

Comment: In general its not a good idea to catch all exceptions in the dark. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7590530/2295964).

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  I was writing a monitoring app where it is critical to keep up and keep moving. It seems the OP was struggling with just finding out what the issue was.  All the other answers are about specific issues that could be the cause of this error.  As a debugging step the above is almost always necessary before you can drill down to the real issue.  It is also weird to me that you are OK with your server dying because of one failure, causing all other client calls to start failing?

Answer (score 14):

I just had this problem happen to me and after some searching for an answer I have found this other stackoverflow thread: [ECONNREFUSED error with node.js that does not occur in other clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643965/econnrefused-error-with-node-js-that-does-not-occur-in-other-clients)

The solution provided there, worked for me like a charm, it seems nodeJS has some issues accessing localhost dns, however switching to 127.0.0.1 works perfectly fine.

Comment: i'm annoyed that this is what worked for me... your like answer number unteen on this question :/

Comment: @Ayyash sorry about that, but at least you found it in the end. :)

Answer (score 11):

You're trying to connect to localhost:8080 ... is any service running on your localhost and on this port? If not, the connection is refused which cause this error. I would suggest to check if there is anything running on localhost:8080 first.

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same issue with ghost and heroku.

```
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production
```

solved it!

Check your config and env that the server is running on.

Comment: Can you explain why this fixes the issue?

Comment: I used heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false.  I would like to know how that worked though

Answer (score 7):

You need to have a server running on port 8080 when you run the code above that simply returns the request back through the response.  Copy the code below to a separate file (say 'server.js') and start this server using the node command (node server.js). You can then separately run your code above (node app.js) from a separate command line.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response){

    //The following code will print out the incoming request text
    request.pipe(response);

}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Listening on port 8080...');
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are on MEAN (Mongo-Express-AngularJS-Node) stack, run mongod first, and this error message will go away.

Comment: 2 days of search and then I saw your comment, saved my day

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes it may occur, if there is any database connection in your code but you did not start the database server yet.

Im my case i have some piece of code to connect with mongodb

`mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/demoDb");`

after i started the mongodb server with the command **mongod** this error is gone

Answer (score 5):

`ECONNREFUSED` error means that connection could not be made with the target service (in your case `localhost:8080`). Check your service running on port 8080.

To know more about node.js errors, refer this [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html).

Answer (score 3):

People run into this error when the Node.js process is still running and they are attempting to start the server again. Try this:

`ps aux | grep node`

This will print something along the lines of:

```
user    7668  4.3  1.0  42060 10708 pts/1    Sl+  20:36   0:00 node server
user    7749  0.0  0.0   4384   832 pts/8    S+   20:37   0:00 grep --color=auto node
```

In this case, the process will be the one with the pid 7668. To kill it and restart the server, run `kill -9 7668`.

Comment: That's not the problem here.  He's getting connection refused when trying to make a request.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using NodeJs version > 17, try to downgrade to use NodeJs 16.
On 17, by default, the debugger bind IP is on IPv6, and sometimes you IDE might not be able to attach to it

Comment: Thank you @Steven Shi! This was the issue for me. I had disabled IPv6 on my router previously, and turning it back plus mapping 6to4 fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

In NodeJs version > 17, the debugger bind IP is on IPv6, so first you should map your IP to IPv6 then use that in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Check with starting mysql in terminal. Use below command

`mysql-ctl start`

In my case its worked

Answer (score 1):

Run server.js from a different command line and client.js from a different command line

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a problem in library `node-agent-base v4.x` which was requested by `https-proxy-agent` which in it's side was requested by `newrelic v5.x` library.

The problem was that `node-agent-base v4.x` for some marvellous idea decided to patch core https.get request (You can see this in the file `patch-core.js` in the repo). And when I used library which use https.get, it was failed because `node-agent-base v4.x` have changed function signature, which gave me request to 127.0.0.1 as initial url was lost...

I've fixed this by updating to the next version of `newrelic 6.x`, where  `node-agent-base v4.x` doesn't has such 'patches'.

This is just crazy...hope my response will save you some time, I've spent several days to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

The `Unhandled 'error' event` is referring not providing a function to the request to pass errors.  Without this event the node process ends with the error instead of failing gracefully and providing actual feedback.  You can set the event just before the `request.write` line to catch any issues:

```
request.on('error', function(err)
{
    console.log(err);
});
```

More examples below:

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, it turned out the listening port printed was different from what it actually was. Typos in the request string or listening function might make the target server appear to not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forget to `npm start` the node app

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened when my .env file was named incorrectly to .env.local

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The name provided to Docker is the hostname to use when connecting to that host. For example, if your service is named "couchdb" you could access it from another container like "curl couchdb:5984".

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

> When you run docker compose up, the following happens:
>
> 1. A network called myapp_default is created.
> 2. A container is created using web’s configuration. It joins the network myapp_default under the name web.
> 3. A container is created using db’s configuration. It joins the network myapp_default under the name db.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue in my dev env with Postman when checking the API.
I searched literally all the answers came from google, but no avail.

SOLUTION:
I have just moved to "insomnia" (an alternative to Postman) and it works just fine. Hope this workaround may help.