# REST client proxy issue in VScode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, proxy

When using the REST client extension in VSCode eg.

```
Send Request
GET http://localhost:4200/dashboard

###
```

I get following error :

```
Connection is being rejected. The service isn’t running on the server,
or incorrect proxy settings in vscode, or a firewall is blocking requests.
Details: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4200
```

How can I change my http-proxy to 4200 instead of 127.0.0.1:4200 ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the VSCode itself. It's that you're most probably using WSL2 and your client is not able to convert your localhost hostname into your WSL2 vm's IP address. One dirty quick solution is ip a | grep inet in your WSL2 and use its IP address instead of localhost in your request URLs, which is a bad idea since WSL2 IP address is not static (it will change). The other solution is using a client that is able to work for WSL2 users too (Postman as an example).

Answer (score 5):

The solution that works for me, it's to change the server hostname with a string (hostname: "127.0.0.1").

**Deno/TS/Rest client Extension vscode**

***app.ts***

```
import { Drash } from "https://deno.land/x/drash@v1.4.3/mod.ts";
import { Api } from "./api.ts";

const server = new Drash.Http.Server({
  response_output: "application/json",
  resources: [Api],
});

server.run({
  hostname: "127.0.0.1", // Just here !
  port: 1854,
});

console.log("Server running...");
```

***api.ts***

```
// @ts-ignore
import { Drash } from "https://deno.land/x/drash@v1.4.3/mod.ts";

export class Api extends Drash.Http.Resource {
  static paths = ["/"];
  public GET() {
    this.response.body = `Hello World! (on ${new Date()})`;
    return this.response;
  }
}
```

***req.http***

```
GET http://localhost:1854/ HTTP/1.1
```

OR

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:1854/ HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Great answer. In my case, I was running Firebase Serve, which by default was using localhost, so I simply had to override it with "firebase serve --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5000"

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZlRN.png)It later worked. I realised that the error was with the double quotes in the api.http file and by removing them it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post, I thought my solution might be useful to someone  out there.

In my case, I was working on a WebApi project, and decided to test my endpoint using **Rest Client**. I created a **`abc.http`** file for this purpose.

Firstly, my server wasn't running in VSCode. To start it, I went to **`run and debug`** and hit the **`play`** button.

When I clicked the **`Send Request`** button, I saw the detailed error, which pointed to the type I used in one of my models.

> **System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.DateOnly' instances are not supported...**

I recalled that I had defined a property in my model with the **`DateOnly`** type.

Steps taken to fix issue:

1. Change type from **`DateOnly`** to **`DateTime`**
2. Stop and start server (restart didn't work for me).
3. Click the **`Send Request`** button again.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

### For Windows users

*Please check your hosts file(`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) and confirm these lines are not hashed out*

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

- remove the hashes to uncomment them and save the hosts file then rerun the api server

#### modify the running code

add the `--host 127.0.0.1` flag when running the server