# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 error using Docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I have a javascript file (client.js) that runs node-fetch to make GET requests to my server. My server is listening on port 3000. Whenever I create a Docker container to run the client file, I get the following error:

```
(node:9) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/selectItem/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

When I run the client file without any container, it works fine. I just want to have multiple container instances that run the client.js file.

I tried solutions like [Node.js Error: connect ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168433/node-js-error-connect-econnrefused), but they didn't work.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /client

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD node client
EXPOSE 3000
```

Thank you :)

Comment: localhost inside the container is the container not the host system

Comment: Where is the server running?  (Directly on the host, in another container?)  The client?  (In a browser, in a host Node setup, in a container?)  What commands or actions produce that error message?  Can you connect to the server in other ways?

Comment: @DavidMaze The server is running locally (it is not inside a container). I only have one container and it is running the client.js script (executes web requests). It is possible to connect to the server if the client.js script is not inside a container. The command that produces the error is: docker run -it -p 8000:3000 client

Comment: As @LawrenceCherone says, `localhost` is the container itself and not the host system.  The linked question describes several workarounds.  If you're using Docker Desktop on a Windows or MacOS system, the easiest is to use the special hostname `host.docker.internal` instead.