# how to turn html json file into a useable output that can be displayed

Tags: discord.js

I want to use https://someapi.xyz/json/quote to display a quote when a user uses a command but I'm not really even sure where to start with implementing the html json and using it in a command. Messed around with `snekfetch` a bit but I don't think I had the setup correct so it didn't work.
Here's what I tried:

```js
const api = "https://someapi.xyz/json/quote";
const snekfetch = require('snekfetch');

module.exports = {
    name: "quote",
    description: "sends inspirational quote",
    async execute(message, args, Discord) {
snekfetch.get(api).then(console.log);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code so far? How do you store that response

Comment: @Elitezen I was trying to just console log the message with [this](https://sourceb.in/nA0G5gBFvJ) but I get no response

Comment: Please edit the code into your question

Comment: Got it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is JSON data, access the body then use it as any other JavaScript Object.

```js
const api = "https://someapi.xyz/json/quote";
const snekfetch = require('snekfetch');

module.exports = {
    name: "quote",
    description: "sends inspirational quote",
    async execute(message, args, Discord) {
        snekfetch.get(api)
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.body;
                message.channel.send(`Quote from ${data.author}: ${data.quote}`);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Got a syntax error saying: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` so I tried to stringify `res` which sends the message but the author and quote are undefined.

Comment: What do you get when you log `res`

Comment: Try accessing the `body` property of the result, I've updated my answer

Comment: Refer to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168433/node-js-error-connect-econnrefused) for more information