# Cpanel Email not sending on live site

Tags: node.js, email, cpanel

I have a cpanel email that can send mails with a nodejs application. However this only works locally. When I try on the live site, I get this error:

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {

errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',

code: 'ESOCKET',

syscall: 'connect',

port: 465,

command: 'CONN'
}

I heard it's a firewall issue. If it is, how can I enable port 465 in my cpanel. Or how can I change to a different port? Please graphical solutions would be applicated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js Error: connect ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168433/node-js-error-connect-econnrefused)

Comment: It seems its from a port in my firewall